# Use jQuery to change values of all input fields to include an escape character

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit

I need to use jQuery to change the value of any input field (on form submit) to an escaped value.

If the user types an apostrophe, I need it to change to an escaped value before it is submitted and inserted into my database:

```
' ---> /'
```

How do I get jQuery to check all input fields and textareas for an apostrophe upon submitting, change the value, then continue with the submit function?

EDIT:
I understand this is not a secure method of handling such a request, but I do not have access to the server side code. Also, as this is on an intranet, I'm not looking for the most secure solution, just one that uses JavaScript to handle it.

Comments so far have been limited to describing why this is a bad practice. Would anyone know how to actually handle this request using JavaScript (preferably jQuery)?

Comment: This is a bad, bad idea. You should cleanse the input on the server side or use prepared statements for inserting data into your database.

Comment: You really should do that replacement server side... or better let your DB API do it for you. Sanitizing fields client side for DB insertion is **terribly wrong**.

Comment: You better off use mysql_real_escape_string serverside (in case you use PHP). If a malicious user manipulates the packets, he can manipulate the output of jQuery (that what you ment to sent to the server) and thus pretty easily inject data into your mySQL query. Never ever apply such critical security things on the client side.

Comment: @dihakz Sadly there is no alternative than doing it server side. But you really should not have to worry about it and use prepared statements or similar solutions.

Comment: If you have no access to the server part, built some sort of proxying API that does this, but still, serverside.

Comment: Is there no way to actually do this using jQuery, even in theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside the fact that this is easily circumventable, and just dealing with the specific requirement of escaping apostrophes from all text inputs on submit, here's one method:

- Use [the jQuery `submit` function](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to bind an event handler.
- In the handler use a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to find all the `textarea` and
  `input type='text'` fields on the form (probably using [the multiple
  selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and the appropiate standard CSS selector syntax by [type](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Selectors/type_selector) and [attribute](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Selectors/attribute_selector/attribute)).
- Once you have the jQuery object containing all the inputs ([the `length` property](http://api.jquery.com/category/properties/jquery-object-instance-properties/) will help you verify that), you need to [loop over `.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) one, passing in a function that
  likely uses [the `replace` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to change the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

That's a pretty link heavy set of steps, but it should give you what you need to start understanding jQuery based event handling and DOM traversal and manipulation.

Comment: Thank you -- this was a great method.